# python patch. get Mock rather than MagicMock (with autospec)

Tags: python, python-unittest

How I can get `Mock` object as patch result rather than `MagicMock` in this short sample?

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock


class X:
    x=1


with patch.object(X, 'x', autospec=True) as my_mock:
    print(type(my_mock))  # NonCallableMagicMock, but need just a Mock/NonCallableMock
```

Comment: What breaks if you have a `MagicMock` instead of a regular `Mock`?

Comment: @chepner I'm checking call count by `assert len(my_mock.mock_calls) == 1`

Comment: And? What code do you have where the different between a `Mock` and a `MagicMock` matters? (You may need a better example; here, you're mocking something that is an *integer*, which should shouldn't expect to be called *at all*.)

Comment: @chepner `MagicMock` will trigger on `or`, `if`, `bool`, etc.

Comment: Could you please just provide a [mcve] that demonstrates how `MagicMock` causes a problem?

Comment: @chepner okay, just addd this 2 lines at the end of code sample in the question.
`my_mock or 1; print(my_mock.mock_calls)  # [call.__bool__()]`
`my_mock  or 1` causes implicit behavior, it's differ from `Mock` behavior.

Comment: I'm not disputing that there's an observable difference; I'm asking what test you are writing that cares about the difference.

Comment: The trivial solution is to not use `autospec` and create a `Mock` manually with whatever you need to make your test meaningful.

Comment: @chepner You are a genius. How did I miss this before!